# Can i install cPanel or plesk control panel

Tags: linux

I have got rackspace cloud server and i have installed lamstack and more. Its too hard to use command prompt to my client, so he wants  cPanel or plesk control panel. Is it possible to install any one of those? Which one is best and free or open source. Please suggest me.

Comment: You can also take a look at ISPConfig-3 http://www.ispconfig.org/ispconfig-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cPanel and Plesk will cost you plenty i suppose because rackspace is not their reseller. You might want to look into webmin.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Here i got a link to install cpanel. http://installatron.com/install_cpanelwhm . Will it work or will it make any porblem?

Comment: As the RS cloud server is technically a VPS, you will need the cPanel VPS optimized version. You can get that from resellers listed on the cPanel site, it would probably cost you around $20 a month or so.

Answer (score 1):

VHCS is ok, i use it for simple webhosting, email, ftp and database administration.

doesn't do a lot else though. its good beside webmin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if people are still following this question, but for those that find it VHCS is no longer being supported and is being improved under from a new name called IspCP.  Neither of them are particularly easy to install on linux servers and they are not that good.  Webmin is the easiest to install and the most written about for support.